# Error in producing data to Kafka using Erlang/ekaf

Tags: erlang, apache-kafka

I'm trying to connect Kafka and produce some messages using Erlang/[ekaf](https://github.com/helpshift/ekaf).

The code is a simple example explained in ekaf's README, but will exit when `application:start` is called.

Please note that I've used `gen_icmp:ping` to make sure the server running Kafka is accessible to this machine.

I have also run python script to produce some random message to this Kafka and it was successful, so most probably there is something I have missed in my Erlang code. :)

Source:

```
-module(kafka).
-compile(export_all).


run_test() ->
    io:format("run_test: start.~n"),
    pingKafka(),

    try init_ekaf() of
        _ -> io:format("run_test: ok~n")
    catch 
        error:Msg -> io:format("run_test: error: ~p~n", [Msg]);
        throw:Msg -> io:format("run_test: throw: ~p~n", [Msg]);
        exit:Msg -> io:format("run_test: exit: ~p~n", [Msg])
    end.


init_ekaf() ->
    io:format("init_ekaf: start.~n"),

    application:load(ekaf),
    application:set_env(ekaf, ekaf_bootstrap_broker, {"kafka.dev", 9092}),
    ok = application:start(ekaf),
    io:format("init_ekaf: started.~n"),

    Topic = <<"foobar">>,
    ekaf:produce_sync(Topic, <<"some data">>),
    io:format("init_ekaf: message sent.~n"),
    ok.


pingKafka() ->
    Res = gen_icmp:ping("kafka.dev"),
    io:format("pingKafka: ~p.~n", [Res]),
    ok.
```

Output:

```
run_test: start.
pingKafka: [{ok,"kafka.dev",
                {192,168,0,51},
                {192,168,0,51},
                {12343,0,64,130},
                <<" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJK">>}].
init_ekaf: start.
run_test: error: {badmatch,{error,{not_started,gproc}}}
run_test: end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading existing tests in the repository again, I find out that `gproc` application also need to be started before starting ekaf.

So by adding:

```
application:start(gproc)
```

right before `application:start(ekaf)`, the problem solved.

P.S: Found another way to solve the issue which is calling `application:ensure_all_started(ekaf)` instead of `application:start(ekaf)`.
As mentioned in [document](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#ensure_all_started-1), `ensure_all_started` is an equivalent to calling start/1,2 repeatedly on all dependencies that are not yet started for an application